# Сервисозависимая конфигурация с consul

Tags: java, spring, config

Добрый день!

Микросервисы (Spring) после деплоя забирают конфиги из `key/value` хранилища `consul`. Для сервисов из `dev`, `test` или `prod` окружений конфиги идентичны.

Но могут быть такие ситуации, когда сервисы разных версий используют различные значения: 
допустим сервис версии 0.7 должен использовать ключ `global.config.timeout` со значением `2000`, а версии `0.8` - со значением `5000`.

Идея о версионировании ключей в `consul` была руководством отвергнута.

Ну и в связи со всем вышесказанным вопрос:
может быть существуют какие-либо другие реализации сервисозависимых конфигураций?